# TS typings: How to access to namespace inside module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

While using Typescript at work I encountered many dependencies that doesn't have the typings, both in project or in @types on NPM. While for some I was able to create on my own, in the case of youbora ([here is the public source code @ bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/npaw/lib-plugin-js/src/49d610d64198/src/?at=master)), a QA library for video players, I cannot create them: particularly I get stuck with namespaces.

Youbora let the developer to use it by creating a Plugin and registering an adapter.

```js
import * as youbora from "youboralib";
import "youbora-adapter-shaka";

// ---- in my classes ----

this.youbora = new youbora.Plugin({ ... });
```

In another class/component (we are using react with typescript):

```js
this.props.youbora.setAdapter(
    new youbora.adapters.Shaka(document.getElementById("videoContent"))
);
```

Typescript tells me that "youboralib" (which is the package name on NPM) has no declarations files. So I created it looking at the source code.

```js
declare module "youboralib" {
  class Plugin {
    constructor(options: YouboraNS.PluginOpts, adapter?: YouboraNS.Adapter);
    setAdapter(adapter: YouboraNS.Adapter): void
    // ...
  }

  namespace adapters {}

  namespace YouboraNS {
    interface PluginOpts {}
    interface Adapter {
      plugin: any
    }
    interface Communication {}
  }
}
```

As we only include Plugin class, there are no problems.

`Youbora.adapters`, per the source code, is an empty object that gets populated by the imported adapters (like above, `youbora-adapter-shaka`). So it is possible to do, as above, `new youbora.adapters.Shaka(...)`.

In terms on typings, it should be a namespace (as written).
The problem is that if I declare a namespace in the module, I cannot access to it from the outside but only from the inside (as YouboraNS): in fact, VSCode suggests me only `Plugin` class. I made different searches across the web and SO but got no results.

So the problem here is: how can I access to a module-specific namespace?

To bypass this problem, I had to disable the flag `tsconfig.CompilerOptions.noImplicitAny` and / or use `@ts-ignore` above the instructions, but they are a so ugly solutions.

========================

If you look at [the code of `youboralib.js`](https://bitbucket.org/npaw/lib-plugin-js/src/49d610d64198fc0bd549c82166c373b51a48cf69/src/youboralib.js), you can see that actually "youbora" can be considered as a namespace itself, as it is an object with different properties.

So I tried to define it as a namespace, but still VSCode doesn't recognize it as a module:

```js
export = youboralib;
export as namespace youboralib;

declare namespace youboralib {
  class Plugin { ... }
  namespace adapters {}
}
```

I tried also with `export namespace adapters {}` or something like this but got nothing different.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The namespace should be there, but if its empty it will probably not get suggested for types or for values. You can use namespace from outside. Try `let o: y.YouboraNS.Adapter;` (where `y` is the import). Since `YouboraNS` does not contain any values it will only be suggested in type annotations

Comment: You are right, @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. It must not be empty and contain something, a class, a function to be suggested. I think that it should be instead suggested but nevermind!
In my case, I can insert in it the Shaka function as these are internal typings (for the current project). But what if youbora decides to create their own typings, for example? They would stuck in the same situation I did.

Comment: They can declare the namespace just as you did. Other modules (the ones with the plugins) will use module augmentations and will add to the namespace and when they do it will appear where it might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought the same: I created the empty namespace in youboralib and then created another declaration file called `youbora-adapter-shaka` that imports `youboralib` and extends it, like declaring it again. That's great!!

Thank you again! 